# Transpose and insert multiple rows with differing values

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, pivot, unpivot

I have a more complicated version of the following table:

```
ID | FIRST  | LAST     | EMAIL
1  | John   | Doe      | jdoe@example.com
1  | Mack   | Johnson  | mjohnson@example.com
1  | Steven | Michaels | smichaels@example.com
2  | Sarah  | Sampson  | ssampson@example.com
2  | Tom    | Smith    | tsmith@example.com
2  | Jane   | Rogers   | jrogers@example.com
3  | Bob    | Johns    | bjohns@example.com
3  | Kim    | Lane     | klane@example.com
3  | Ron    | Swanson  | rswanson@example.com
```

and I would like to write one query that inserts this data into another table to look like this (the table already exists):

```
ID | first1 | last1    | email1               | first2 | last2    | email2               | first3 | last3    | email3 
1  | John   | Doe      | jdoe@example.com     | Mack   | Johnson  | mjohnson@example.com | Steven | Michaels | smichaels@example.com
2  | Sarah  | Sampson  | ssampson@example.com | Tom    | Smith    | tsmith@example.com   | Jane   | Rogers      | jrogers@example.com
3  | Bob    | Johns    | bjohns@example.com   | Kim    | Lane     | klane@example.com    | Ron    | Swanson     | rswanson@example.com
```

I feel that this should be easy but the concept is eluding me. What is best practice for accomplishing this?

Maybe I should also mention that I have written a function that I can pass the ID, an index number, and a column name to return a value (i.e. getpersoninfo(2,'1','first') to return Sarah).

```
select a_id,
  FIRST1, LAST1, EMAIL1,
  FIRST2, LAST2, EMAIL2,
  FIRST3, LAST3, EMAIL3
from
(
  select a_id, col||rn as new_col, value
  from
  (
    select a_id, first_name, last_name, email,
      cast(row_number() over(partition by a_id order by a_id) as varchar2(10)) rn
    from dump_recs_2015
  ) 
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (first_name, last_name, email)
  )
) 
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for new_col in ('FIRST1' FIRST1, 'LAST1' LAST1, 'EMAIL1' EMAIL1,
                  'FIRST2' FIRST2, 'LAST2' LAST2, 'EMAIL2' EMAIL2,
                  'FIRST3' FIRST3, 'LAST3' LAST3, 'EMAIL3' EMAIL3)
);
```

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Will you only ever have 3 entries per `ID`?

Comment: 11g. Some will have two but at most 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Oracle 11g, you can implement both the [`UNPIVOT`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) and [`PIVOT`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) functions.

The `UNPIVOT` will take your columns `first`, `last` and `email` and convert the values into rows. Then you can `PIVOT` the new names `First1`, etc into columns:

```
select id,
  First1, Last1, Email1,
  First2, Last2, Email2,
  First3, Last3, Email3
from
(
  select id, col||rn as new_col, value
  from
  (
    select id, first, last, email,
      cast(row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as varchar2(10)) rn
    from yourtable
  ) 
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (first, last, email)
  )
) 
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for new_col in ('FIRST1' First1, 'LAST1' Last1, 'EMAIL1' Email1,
                  'FIRST2' First2, 'LAST2' Last2, 'EMAIL2' Email2,
                  'FIRST3' First3, 'LAST3' Last3, 'EMAIL3' Email3)
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89974/11). This can then be used in an `INSERT` statement to load the data into a new table.

Edit, based on your column name changes, you will use:

```
select a_id,
  First1, Last1, Email1,
  First2, Last2, Email2,
  First3, Last3, Email3
from
(
  select a_id, col||rn as new_col, value
  from
  (
    select a_id, first_name, last_name, email,
      cast(row_number() over(partition by a_id order by a_id) as varchar2(10)) rn
    from yourtable
  ) 
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (first_name, last_name, email)
  )
) 
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for new_col in ('FIRST_NAME1' First1, 'LAST_NAME1' Last1, 'EMAIL1' Email1,
                  'FIRST_NAME2' First2, 'LAST_NAME2' Last2, 'EMAIL2' Email2,
                  'FIRST_NAME3' First3, 'LAST_NAME3' Last3, 'EMAIL3' Email3)
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd15d/1)

Comment: This is awesome. Making some changes to be compatible with my actual column names my first and last names are coming up null.

Comment: I've added my changes above.

Comment: @sgd See my edit, you just have to change the column names used in the `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` blocks.

Comment: Hmmm. That looks exactly like what I have. Except that one works fully. Anyway, thanks for the tip. This thing works great and is giving my day a pleasant end. Thanks, again.